# Query complex in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following tables and their fields

[image]

They ask me for a query that seems to me quite complex, I have been going around for two days and trying things, it says:

> It is desired to obtain the average age of female athletes, medal winners (gold, silver or bronze), for the different modalities of 'Artistic Gymnastics'. Analyze the possible contents of the result field in order to return only the expected values, even when there is no data of any specific value for the set of records displayed by the query. Specifically, we want to show the gender indicator of the athletes, the medal obtained, and the average age of these athletes. The age will be calculated by subtracting from the system date (SYSDATE), the date of birth of the athlete, dividing said value by 365. In order to avoid showing decimals, truncate (TRUNC) the result of the calculation of age. Order the results by the average age of the athletes.

Well right now I have this:

```
select person.gender,score.score
from person,athlete,score,competition,sport
where person.idperson = athlete.idathlete    and
athlete.idathlete=  score.idathlete  and
competition.idsport = sport.idsport and
person.gender='F' and competition.idsport=18 and score.score in 
('Gold','Silver','Bronze')
group by 
person.gender,
score.score;
```

And I got this out

[image]

By adding the person.birthdate field instead of leaving 18 records of the 18 people who have a medal, I'm going to many more records.

Apart from that, I still have to draw the average age with SYSDATE and TRUNC that I try in many ways but I do not get it.

[image]

I see it very complicated or I'm a bit saturated from so much spinning, I need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the task you got, it seems that you're quite close to the solution. Have a look at the following query and its explanation, note the differences from your query, see if it helps.

```
select p.gender,
       ((sysdate - p.birthday) / 365) age,
       s.score
from person p join athlete a on a.idathlete = p.idperson       
              left join score s on s.idathlete = a.idathlete
              left join competition c on c.idcompetition = s.idcompetition
where p.gender = 'F'
  and s.score in ('Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze')
  and c.idsport = 18
order by age;
```

- when two dates are subtracted, the result is number of days. Dividing it by 365, you - roughly - get number of years (as each year has 365 days - that's for simplicity, of course, as not all years have that many days (hint: leap years)). The result is usually a decimal number, e.g. `23.912874918724`. In order to avoid that, you were told to remove decimals, so - use `TRUNC` and get `23` as the result
- although data model contains 5 tables, you don't *have to* use all of them in a query. Maybe the best approach is to go step-by-step. The first one would be to simply select all female athletes and calculate their age:

  ```
  select p.gender,
         ((sysdate - p.birthday) / 365 age
  from person p
  where p.gender = 'F'
  ```

  Note that I've used a table **alias** - I'd suggest you to use them too, as they make queries easier to read (table names can have really long names which don't help in readability). Also, **always** use table aliases to avoid confusion (which column belongs to which table)
- Once you're satisfied with that result, move on to another table - `athlete` It is here just as a *joining mechanism* with the `score` table that contains ... well, *scores*. Note that I've used **outer join** for the `score` table because not all athletes have won the medal. I presume that this is what the task you've been given says:

  > ... even when there is no data of any specific value for the set of records displayed by the query.
- It is suggested that we - as developers - use explicit table joins which let you to see all joins separated from filters (which should be part of the `WHERE` clause). So:

  ```
  NO : from person p, athlete a
       where a.idathlete = p.idperson
         and p.gender = 'F'

  YES: from person p join athlete a on a.idathlete = p.idperson
       where p.gender = 'F'
  ```
- Then move to yet another table, and so forth.
- Test frequently, all the time - don't skip steps. Move on to another one only when you're sure that the previous step's result is correct, as - in most cases - it won't automagically fix itself.

Comment: (Upvoted!) Apparently, they will be needing the SPORTS table, too - as 'Artistic Gymnastics'
is required (will probably be mentioned in the WHERE clause later on) - so: one JOIN is missing.  The
main difficulty, though, seems to be the nested function call using AVG() and TRUNC().
Maybe you could add some code demonstrating this.

Comment: @Littlefoot My problem is that in all the examples I have never use the join or left join, always use equalities between the tables, I mean, to join the tables always use "NameTable.FieldTable" = "NameTable.FieldTable".

On the other hand, try what you put me, I went little by little and the age issue does not work, it tells me that "Error inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE", this I guess it will be because the birthday field is of type char.

On the other hand, they ask me to order by the average of the ages. How is the average age?

I'm close but still with doubts

Comment: @stefan Really the sport "Artistic Gymnastics" already I take it out with its idSport that is = 18, that already I have it.

I need the issue of getting the age of each gymnast taking into account the current date "Sysdate" and that the birthday field is char type and you see the average as you say with the avg ... But do not use it.

I'm very close but I can not get it.

Comment: @Roman345 If the date is stored as varchar2, you need to convert it into a DATE.  I've written a little example for you (encompassing TO_DATE(), SYSDATE, TRUNC() and AVG()), using the first 3 BIRTHDATEs of your question in a small table.  See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3301bd9bfeb8fbf655158a8d475ade5c

Comment: @stefan The data is a CHAR (10 BYTE) that is entered in the database '22 / 05/2018 'for example.

Use what you put me like this: select trunc (avg (sysdate - to_date (person.birthday, 'DD / MM / YYYY'))) trunc_avg_diff
from person;

But I get error:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 - "inconsistent datatypes: expected% s got% s"

Apart I have to divide it between 365, I notice that I am, we are very close but I do not get it.

Regarding the joins that you think? We do not use them, we use equalizations.

Comment: @Roman345 (1) if the date ist stored as CHAR, you can still use TO_DATE. (2) Joins should be done via JOIN .. ON .. (join conditions 
written in the WHERE clause are a bit old-fashioned. (3) divide by 365 : see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76851f789de6562c6e223076e0093f1f Another thing: we should not continue the discussion here in the COMMENTS section.  Instead, EDIT your question or ask a NEW question.